# Cast collection of pairs to map without triggering compiler warning

Tags: kotlin, casting

I'm trying to transform a data structure of type `List<Pair<String, MyCustomType?>` into `Map<String, MyCustomType>` **without using mutable data types** (i.e. no `HashMap.put` or similar things).

My current approach looks like this:

```
pairs
  .filter { it.second != null }
  .toMap() as Map<String, MyCustomDataType>
```

which works, **but** leads to a compiler warning for the last line:

```
Unchecked cast: Map<String, MyCustomDataType?> to Map<String, MyCustomDataType>
```

Do you see a solution that gets rid of the compiler warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `filter` function you only removed all of the elements from the list that had second parameter as `null`. **It does not change the element type of the list**.

In order to do what you want you will have to create new instances of `Pair` object that will not allow to store `null` values. No casting will be required.

```
pairs
    .filter { it.second != null }
    .map { Pair(it.first, it.second!!) }
```

If the list is large combine `filter` and `map` functions. It will be faster and the result is still the same, only aesthetics suffer:

```
listOfPairs
    .mapNotNull { 
        if (it.second != null) {
            Pair(it.first, it.second!!)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used `pairs.mapNotNull { pair -> pair.second?.let { Pair(pair.first, it) } }` in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know what you're doing, and compiler isn't that smart enough to detect if its not null. You can suppress the warning simply (instead of creating multiple steps).

```kotlin
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
pairs
  .filter { it.second != null }
  .toMap() as Map<String, MyCustomDataType>
```